# Rails: view based on a different model-controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view, model

I am using two different models&controllers - say `products` and `checkout`, but I want the `checkout` to be ordered by the `product` number. (Meaning checkout for product number 5, checkout for product number 7 etc.)

How do I go about this? Should I use another `view` under `products` but connect it to the `checkout` controller and model? How can I do that? What do I need to configure and where? Routes? other?

Alternatively, should I use a `checkout` view, but somehow make sure that the ID/numbering of the view is based on the `products`? How can I do that? What do I need to configure and where? Routes? other?

Comment: what kind of associations the two models have which each other? 1:n?

Comment: product `has_many` checkouts

Answer (score 0):

For rendering all checkouts dependent on the associated product you can do like following:

routes.rb

```
resources :checkouts
```

checkout_controller.rb

```
def index
  @checkouts = Checkout.order("product_id asc")
end
```

app/views/checkouts/index.html.erb

```
<% @checkouts.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I only want one checkout at a time though, one for each user. How do I include it within the view for `product`?

Comment: how is the user associated with the products or checkouts? please give me more information about the user model.

Comment: Does it matter? How do I refer in the view, to another class/controller (other than the current one)? Can't I refer to it somehow? Say I'm in the `product` view, I wan't to enable to `checkout` from there, how do I refer to the `checkout` class? do I need to move the `checkout` class/controller into the `product` one?

Comment: you always can call for example Checkout.all in the products controller or any view. Sorry, I do not really understand your question :).

Comment: Here's the same question, more detailed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375921/referring-to-2-classes-controllers-from-one-view-in-a-rails-application